# Java Fiscal Year Week Counter

Tags: java, date

I've been all up night trying to figure this out, but nothing I try seems to work. Let say the Fiscal year starts on 10/01 of every year, for example the fiscal year started on 10/01/2012 making this week number 30. I can't seem to find the code that returns the appropriate week number.

The closest I've gotten is this code below which returns week number 16 starting from Jan.

```
public String getCurrentWeek() {
        GregorianCalendar current = new GregorianCalendar(getCalendar().get(Calendar.YEAR),
            getCalendar().get(Calendar.MONTH), getCalendar().get(Calendar.DATE));

        return Integer.toString(current.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
    }
```

Comment: Since you know when the fiscal year starts, just extract correct week information and adjust it accordingly to first day of the fiscal year ween number (usually is weekOfTheSolarYear - weekOfStartOfFiscalYear)

Comment: Please, please, don't use dates like "10/01". I have no idea if that's in American or international format, and hence whether it's in January or October. If you're going to write digits, use [ISO 8601](http://www.iso.org/iso/support/faqs/faqs_widely_used_standards/widely_used_standards_other/date_and_time_format.htm), or else use a textual month.

Comment: Also, where are you getting week number 30 from? I assume 10/01/2012 is the 10th of January, since we haven't had the 1st of October yet. It hasn't been 30 weeks since the 10th of January.

Comment: What if a fiscal year starts on a thursday? Will the week then go from thursday to wednesday?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say 01 OCT 2012. From this date to now we are currently at week 30. The week starts on Monday and ends on Friday.

Comment: 1st of October 2012? You've achieved time travel, but you can't do calendrical computations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe:

```
private static final int LENGTH_OF_WEEK = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

public static int weekOf(Calendar yearStart, Calendar date) {
    long millisElapsed = date.getTimeInMillis() - yearStart.getTimeInMillis();
    int weeksElapsed = (int) (millisElapsed / LENGTH_OF_WEEK);
    return weeksElapsed + 1;
}
```

Should do it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently using your code with some modification and I get the wanted result. I had to use weeksElapsed + 2 to get the proper week number.

Comment: I realize that this is an old question but I think a better solution would use the Java 8 time classes and stick to pure 'day based' (e.g. using LocalDate) not 'millisecond based' (e.g. using Date/Calendar) calculations. With millisecond based classes I always worry about any boundary conditions day light savings may introduce.